# Transferring image storage between firebase projects

Tags: firebase, firebase-storage, gsutil

I am trying to transfer 2 folders from an old project into a new project, I have used this command in the past to pass between projects:

`gsutil cp -r gs://oldProjectAPIURL/{folder name} gs://newProjectURL`

But I am not sure if it will overwrite the existing folders, since they have the same name, how can you import these folders without overwriting the existing folders, assuming they have the same names?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A folder is an artificial construct on Google Cloud Storage. In reality it has a flat list of files, and interprets `/` in the path as a directory separator in the SDKs.

That also allows us to answer your question: if you write files to an existing directory, they will be merged with the existing files in there, as on the flat list of files these are unique names that just happen to have the same prefix.